# What's the correct name of the Camera pyramid-shaped wireframe object used to display it?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I want to refer, in technical text, to the wireframe widget that is used to display a camera in Blender model view.

The following image displays two of these:

[image]

Comment: The... camera? It also represents the *field of view* based on how wide it is. The arrow just points up to show which part is the top.

Comment: @Keavon field of view is a concept. I am sure I have already seen the name of this symbol somewhere, and I imagine the dev team must refer to it by some meaningful way that makes clear they are talking about the visual icon, not the concept.

Comment: While Blender doesn't represent near or far planes with its camera gizmo, you may be looking for the word [view frustum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). If that's correct, tell me so I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Keavon Yes, that is what I was looking for, "Camera Frustum" or "Pyramid of Vision". Although the clipping planes are not shown in Blender and others, that is what the symbol semantically represents, I believe. If you can elaborate it into an answer, I'll be glad to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @heltonbiker I would call it the 'representation of the camera'. A frustum is related but completely different.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Blender. Should it be closed?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any standard blender term for the "camera representation" itself. People will probably know what you  mean if you say "wireframe widget that is used to display a camera" though :) (or even just "camera object" or "camera widget").

Comment: This is sort of like asking "What's the name of the shape that a square represents?" "A Square."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pyramid-shaped camera gizmo is just a shape commonly chosen to represent cameras. The pyramid's angle and direction depicts the camera's [**field of view**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view). Unrelated to Blender, the term you are looking for is [**viewing frustum** or **pyramid of vision**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). This is intended for depicting the near and far clipping planes, but Blender does not show these in its camera gizmo. As such, the shape used in Blender is not technically even a frustum because the four segments converge to a point. Within the context of Blender, it is simply called [**the camera**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Camera).

Answer (score 1):

### [The camera](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Camera)

The one on the left is the *active camera*, and the one on the right is not active.

Comment: I want to know the name of the symbol itself, the "gizmo" used to represent camera origin, orientation, fov and if it is active or not.

Comment: @heltonbiker If you look through the datablocks in a blend file you will see that blender refers to the camera as a camera. As to the name of the display, I have only heard of the camera.